# JSON deserialize with custom token

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I need to deserialize an json where the token has special characters, but is not working as expected, it's not passing through the token and comparing to assign, am I forgetting something?

controller:

```
List<JSON2Apex> jsonlist = (List<JSON2Apex>) JSON.deserialize(base64Data, List<JSON2Apex>.class);
```

this following JSON:

```
[{  
      "Booking #":"3321234",
      "Parent Number":"412321",
      "Booking Date":"2017-10-04",
      "Departure Date":"2018-01-13"
   }]
```

I used the tool http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ and it generated the following code:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

public String bookingNumber {get;set;} 
public String parentBooking {get;set;} 
public String bookingDate {get;set;} 
public String departureDate {get;set;}

public JSON2Apex(JSONParser parser) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                if (text == 'Booking #') {
                    bookingNumber = parser.getText();
                } else if (text == 'Parent Booking') {
                    parentBooking = parser.getText();
                } else if (text == 'Booking Date') {
                    bookingDate = parser.getText();
                } else if (text == 'Departure Date') {
                    departureDate = parser.getText();
                } else {
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'JSON2Apex consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                    consumeObject(parser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public static List<JSON2Apex> parse(String json) {
    System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
    return arrayOfJSON2Apex(parser);
}

public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
    Integer depth = 0;
    do {
        System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
            curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            depth++;
        } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
            curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            depth--;
        }
    } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
}

private static List<JSON2Apex> arrayOfJSON2Apex(System.JSONParser p) {
    List<JSON2Apex> res = new List<JSON2Apex>();
    if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
    while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
        res.add(new JSON2Apex(p));
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: You might be better off just using a `Map<String, Object>` here and `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form of the generated code needs to be called rather than passed as a type to the `JSON.deserialize` method so in your controller:

```
List<JSON2Apex> jsonlist = JSON2Apex.parse(base64Data);
```

If your variable `base64Data` does contain encoded data, you will also need to apply `EncodingUtil.base64Decode`.